# Why is {% block content %} causing server 500 error in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have been trying to use the Django template inheritance feature for my project Since I've added {% block content %}s I am now getting a server error 500 whenever I try to run the child template. The base template runs fine. I am quite sure it has something to do with the content blocks, but I'm not sure why as I don't repeat any names of blocks and everything on the child template is contained within a block. The console says two errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Code goes like this:

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
'My style'
</style>

<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'
    {% block title %}
        webpage
    {% endblock %}
    <script>'Jquery reference'</script>
</head>

{% block script %}
    'empty'
{% endblock %}

<body>
<div id='navbar'>
    'My navbar'
</div>

<div id='main_content_block'>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>This is my base</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Home.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title>Home</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
'My javascript'
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
'My content'
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you have an error message and traceback? Can you include it in the question so people have an idea what the issue may be

Comment: Done, I added the errors. Thanks

Comment: I meant the error traceback from the Django application/process

Comment: Yes there's going to be a very clear error message on the server side.

Comment: I am running it using the command prompt and "python manage.py runserver." When I run main.html command prompt gives a similar response: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 and "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179

Comment: I would be tough to figure this out without full traceback. Please look at output in your IDE or set `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` and give us a full traceback.

Comment: Thank you. Figured it out. Django couldn't find base.html and including the absolute path instead of the relative fixed it. Now I know to keep debug on always in development

Answer (score 0):

Django couldn't find base.html and including the absolute path instead of the relative fixed it.